# Gorm Association Delete does not remove rows, instead update rows

Tags: postgresql, windows, go, go-gorm

A client has many Roles. I want to delete all Roles once a client is deleted.

```
 type Client struct {
        Id                          string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
        CreatedAt                   time.Time
        UpdatedAt                   time.Time
        Roles [] Role
    }
    
    type Role struct {
        Id        uint `gorm:"primarykey"`
        CreatedAt time.Time
        UpdatedAt time.Time
    
        ClientID string
    }
    
    return db.Transaction(func(tx *gorm.DB) error {
            err = db.Model(&clientToRemove).Association("Roles").Delete(&clientToRemove.Roles)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
    
            err = db.Delete(&clientToRemove).Error
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
    
            return nil
        })
```

I expect related rows in role to be removed, instead of delete query, it executes an update query to remove client_id.

```
[210.834ms] [rows:1] UPDATE "role" SET "client_id"=NULL WHERE "role"."client_id" = 'xxxxxxxxxxx' AND "role"."id" = 9
```

How to completely remove rows in associated role table?

Database is Postgres

Comment: You could use `ON DELETE CASCADE` for the foreign key in your database schema and then just delete the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-Associations), the delete with association operation will just remove the references between `Client` and `TenantRole`. In your case, it just updated the `TenantRole` records to set the `client_id` to NULL.

If you want to delete the objects as well, you can try using `Select` with the delete operation. Please [note](https://gorm.io/docs/associations.html#Delete-with-Select) that this only works if the primary key is not zero, so your query might look something like this:

```
err = db.Select("TenantRoles").Delete(&Client{Id: clientId}).Error
```

or just use `clientToRemove` if it already has the `Id` field populated

```
err = db.Select("TenantRoles").Delete(&clientToRemove).Error
```